# Unable to Connect to Redis from Spring Boot Application Running on AWS EC2: RedisConnectionException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis

I have EC2 instances on AWS, and my goal is to access a Redis instance located in 'worker 1,' (EC2 Instance named worker 1) which is named 'worker 5,' (EC2 instance named worker 5) from my Spring Boot project within 'worker 1.' For 'worker 1,' I have created a Docker Compose YAML file with the Redis section as follows:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  redis:
    hostname: redis
    image: 'redis'
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.redis == redis
    logging:
      options:
        labels: "serviceName,instanceId"
    labels:
      serviceName: "redis"
      instanceId: "redis"
    networks:
        - messaging-overlay-network
```

And my Spring Boot project's application.yml file looks like this:

```
spring:
  cache:
    redis:
      host: redis
      port: 6379
      time-to-live: 0
    type: redis
```

For Redis configuration, I've created a class as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.cache.redis")
@Setter
public class RedisConfig {

    private String host;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory reactiveRedisConnectionFactory(RedisConfiguration defaultRedisConfig) {
        LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
                .useSsl().and()
                .commandTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(60000)).build();
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(defaultRedisConfig, clientConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisConfiguration defaultRedisConfig() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration config = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        config.setHostName(host);
        return config;
    }
}
```

I opened port in Security Group

[image: Security Group]

However, when trying to use Redis, I'm getting an 'Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to redis:6379' error. Where could the problem be?

Comment: I have no idea what "worker 1" and "worker 5" are from your question. But the `redis` hostname would only work if the SpringBoot app is also running inside that same `docker-compose` docker network. Is the SpringBoot app running in Docker? Is it running on the same server as the Redis server? Please clarify your environment.

Comment: They are inside the same docker compose. Spring boot app is running in docker too. But they are on separate workers. There is a master and when I list services, there are redis and spring app on the list. @MarkB

Comment: Please define what you are calling a "worker". Is a "worker" an EC2 server? As I mentioned already your question is completely unclear.

Comment: They are EC2 servers.

Comment: So the SpringBoot app, and the Redis server, aren't (can't possibly) be running in the "same docker compose" if they are running on completely different servers. The instance of Redis is running on EC2 instance A, inside a docker network created by docker compose, inside that one server. The instance of your SpringBoot app is running on a completely different server, inside a completely different docker network in that server.  You could try changing the `hostname` in your SpringBoot app from `redis` to the Redis EC2 server's private IP.

Answer (score 0):

Adding jedis dependecy;

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
  <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
  <version>3.9.0</version>
</dependency
```

And after that refactor RedisConfig class solved my issue.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.cache.redis")
@Setter
public class RedisConfig {

    private String host;
    private int port;

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration config = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(host, port);
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(config);
    }
}
```